# Json Javascript String Syntax error when parsing an array

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following code javascript code

```
var tasksPlayed = [];
tasksPlayed[90] = true;

var json = JSON.stringify(tasksPlayed);

var output = JSON.parse(json);
```

this gives an error

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse
```

Im not sure why, if I do a .toSource() on the objects I get

```
keyValue:"[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,true]"})
```

Any ideas where I might be going wrong

Answer (score 1):

I don't get this error when I run the code, but the thing with the `null` values is that `tasksPlayed` is an array, so when you set `tasksPlayed[90] = true;`, then it automatically fills all positions from `0` to `89` with `null`. Try using a plain object instead of an array:

```
var tasksPlayed = {};
tasksPlayed[90] = true;

var json = JSON.stringify(tasksPlayed);

var output = JSON.parse(json);
```